# surface parallel to a hyperbolic paraboloid

Tags: calculus, geometry

The equation of hyperbolic paraboloid is

$$z-z_0=\dfrac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^2}-\dfrac{(y-y_0)^2}{b^2}$$

If I consider the cases $z_0=0$ and $z_0=1$, both surfaces should be parallel?

Comment: What do you mean by "parallel" for two surfaces? If you mean "when I walk from point $P$ on surface 1, along the normal direction, I arrive at surface 2 at a distance $d$ that's independent of which $P$ I picked," then the answer (for those surfaces) is "no".

Comment: On the other hand, if by "parallel" you mean "don't intersect", then the answer is "yes".

Comment: One is a translation of the other. Whether or not that makes them “parallel” depends on what you mean by that, as @John Hughes has said.

Comment: but,for example if I wanted to create a shell of thickness h that has the shape of a hyperbolic paraboloid by overlapping several of these surfaces, this would result in a shell or not?

Comment: Do you want the thickness of the shell to be fixed or maintain the shape of hyperbolic paraboloid by the external surface of the shape?

Comment: yes, The separation between the paraboloids must be constant.